# Make header 100% of screen

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a header section 100% of the viewport with  `height: 100vh;`.
But somehow it's overflowing.

When looking in the devtools I see that the cause of this problem comes from my navbar. Here's the structure of the HTML:

```
---body
------header
---------nav
-----------other div
----closing tags
```

Here's the CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
          box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

body {

  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1b1f2a 1.2%, #191d28 1%) 1px 0, #fff;
  background-size: 240px 1px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


header {
  height: 100vh;
}

header nav {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
      grid-template-areas: "brand links email";
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 50px auto 30px auto;
  padding: 10px auto;
}
```

So if I change the header nav top margin to 0 there's no overflow.

Here's a link to the actual project:
https://www.generationz.dev/projects/portfolio1/index.html

So to clarify the question:
How do I to set the header section to be 100% of the viewport without any overflow?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try to add height:100%; under body styles?

Comment: @JamesDeSouza i tried now. doesn't change anything. i would recommend clicking on the link and experimenting with the devtools.

Comment: simply; header nav { margin: 0px auto 30px auto; } header {padding-top:50px; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nav has a top margin of 50px.

```
header nav {
  margin: 50px auto 30px auto;
}
```

The header is set to `height: 100vh`.

So, you're going to get an overflow because: `100vh + 50px > 100%`.

You can remove the top margin on the `nav` or, instead of `height: 100vh` on the header, use `height: calc(100vh - 50px)`. There are other options, such as adding padding or borders. See the MDN excerpt below.

Although the `nav` is nested in the `header`, the `nav` top margin is rendered outside the `header` due to margin collapsing.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing):

> **Mastering Margin Collapsing**
>
> **No content separating parent and descendants.**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context
>   created, or clearance to separate the `margin-top` of a block from the
>   `margin-top` of one or more of its descendant blocks; or no border,
>   padding, inline content, `height`, `min-height`, or `max-height` to
>   separate the `margin-bottom` of a block from the `margin-bottom` of
>   one or more of its descendant blocks, then those margins collapse. ***The
>   collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.***

Another example of margin collapsing:

- [Why is an element with position: fixed moving with a non-positioned sibling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38679945/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left` in header. Then, it will work

```
header {
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: While this maybe solve OP question, you should add more information why you choose this solution. BTW the float not seems the proper method to use (even if it solves this particular issue) since it raise other issues later.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the suggestion.